# Changing icon of application at run time

Tags: vb.net, icons

I am trying to load an icon from a path and set it as a program icon. Any idea how to do that?

I googled it saw a lot of answers but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Me.Icon = New Icon("c:\temp.ico")
```

You can put this in the Form's Load event